# How to hide Floating Menu on Click of Menu Items in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, floating-action-button, swiftui-button

I Created Floating Menu in SwiftUI, but i am stuck in one issue, When press on bottom right plus button i open floating menu items and again press on plus button hide that floating menu items, but when press on menu items it will not hide that menu items.

Below is my code

> MapContainerUIView.swift

```
struct MapContainerUIView: View {
    
    let flotingMenuArray = [
        MenuItemModel(title: "Camera", icon: "camera.fill"),
        MenuItemModel(title: "Photo", icon: "photo.on.rectangle"),
        MenuItemModel(title: "Share", icon: "square.and.arrow.up.fill")
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            ZStack {
                FloatingMenu(dataSource: flotingMenuArray)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func floatingButtonAction(index: Int){
        print("Floating item tap", index)
    }
}
```

> FloatingMenu.swift

```
struct FloatingMenu: View {
    init() {
        self.dataSource = []
    }
    
    init(dataSource: [MenuItemModel]) {
        self.dataSource = dataSource
    }
    
    @State var isMenuShow = false
    
    var dataSource: [MenuItemModel]
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack(alignment: .trailing){
            if isMenuShow{
                Button(action: {
                    self.showMenu()
                }) {
                    Text("")
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                        .background(Color.black)
                        .opacity(0.3)
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            }
            HStack{
                Spacer()
                VStack(alignment: .trailing, content: {
                    Spacer()
                    ForEach(0..<dataSource.count) { index in
                        if isMenuShow {
                            MenuItems(menuItemData: dataSource[index], index: index)
                        }
                    }
                    Button(action: {
                        self.showMenu()
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")
                            .resizable()
                            .frame(width: 60, height: 60)
                            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    }
                    .background(Color.black)
                    .cornerRadius(35)
                })
                .shadow(color: .gray, radius: 4, x: 1, y: 1)
                .padding(.init(top: 0, leading: 20, bottom: 20, trailing: 20))
            }
        }
    }
    
    func showMenu() {
        self.isMenuShow.toggle()
    }
}
```

> MenuItems.swift

```
class MenuItemModel : Identifiable{
    var id = UUID()
    var title : String = ""
    var icon : String = ""
    
    init(title: String, icon: String) {
        self.title = title
        self.icon = icon
    }
}

struct MenuItems: View {
    var mapContainer = MapContainerUIView()
    var menuItemData: MenuItemModel
    var index : Int
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            HStack{
                Text(menuItemData.title)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .shadow(color: .gray, radius: 3, x: 1, y: 1)
                Button(action: {
                    FloatingMenu().isMenuShow = false
                    print("button tap: ", menuItemData.title)
                    self.mapContainer.floatingButtonAction(index: index)
                }) {
                    ZStack {
                        Circle()
                            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                            .frame(width: 45, height: 45)
                            .shadow(color: .gray, radius: 3, x: 1, y: 1)
                        Image(systemName: menuItemData.icon)
                            .imageScale(.large)
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                    }
                    .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 10))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to hide floating menu when press on menu items, please someone guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, you're trying to set `isMenuShow` on a *new instance* of `FloatingMenu`, which is why it isn't working.

One solution is to pass a `Binding` from the original `FloatingMenu` instance.

```
struct MenuItems: View {
    @Binding var isMenuShow : Bool  //<-- Here
    var mapContainer = MapContainerUIView()
    var menuItemData: MenuItemModel
    var index : Int
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            HStack{
                Text(menuItemData.title)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .shadow(color: .gray, radius: 3, x: 1, y: 1)
                Button(action: {
                    self.isMenuShow = false //<-- Here
                    print("button tap: ", menuItemData.title)
                    self.mapContainer.floatingButtonAction(index: index)
                }) {
```

And, in FloatingMenu:

```
if isMenuShow {
  MenuItems(isMenuShow: $isMenuShow, //<-- Here
            menuItemData: dataSource[index],
            index: index)
}
```

---

Another solution would be to provide a closure as an argument to `MenuItems` that closes the menu:

```
struct MenuItems: View {
    var closeMenu : () -> Void //<-- Here
    var mapContainer = MapContainerUIView()
    var menuItemData: MenuItemModel
    var index : Int
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            HStack{
                Text(menuItemData.title)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .shadow(color: .gray, radius: 3, x: 1, y: 1)
                Button(action: {
                    closeMenu()  //<-- Here
                    print("button tap: ", menuItemData.title)
                    //self.mapContainer.floatingButtonAction(index: index)
                }) {
```

```
if isMenuShow {
    MenuItems(closeMenu: { self.isMenuShow = false },
              menuItemData: dataSource[index],
              index: index)
}
```